# Finding nested objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently I am finding nested objects by doing the following

```
let optionToRemove = newSections.find((section) => section.id == this.state.currentSectionId).questions
    .find((question) => question.id == questionId).options
        .find((option) => option.id == optionId)
```

This seems tedious, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Your structure do not allow you a direct lookup for option.id. So your way looks good to me. What would an easier way look like?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that, by the way here it is one:

```
var findNested = function(obj, key, memo) {
      var i,
          proto = Object.prototype,
          ts = proto.toString,
          hasOwn = proto.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);

      if ('[object Array]' !== ts.call(memo)) memo = [];

      for (i in obj) {
        if (hasOwn(i)) {
          if (i === key) {
            memo.push(obj[i]);
          } else if ('[object Array]' === ts.call(obj[i]) || '[object Object]' === ts.call(obj[i])) {
            findNested(obj[i], key, memo);
          }
        }
      }

      return memo;
    }
```

So you can use it like

```js
var findNested = function(obj, key, memo) {
  var i,
    proto = Object.prototype,
    ts = proto.toString,
    hasOwn = proto.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);

  if ('[object Array]' !== ts.call(memo)) memo = [];

  for (i in obj) {
    if (hasOwn(i)) {
      if (i === key) {
        memo.push(obj[i]);
      } else if ('[object Array]' === ts.call(obj[i]) || '[object Object]' === ts.call(obj[i])) {
        findNested(obj[i], key, memo);
      }
    }
  }

  return memo;
}
console.log( findNested({ key: 1}, "key") )
console.log( findNested({ key: 1, inner: { key:2}}, "key") )
console.log( findNested({ key: 1, inner: { another_key:2}}, "another_key") )
```

If you prefer a different approach you can look at the linq library [here](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq) based on the .NET LINQ query language - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)